# Does apple tv support volume control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, airplay

Does anyone know wether apple tv support volume control? Not only by remote, but also use code. I have search the api and use MPVolumeView but no luck. The MPVolumeView will auto hide when airplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest Apple TV, the volume control comes out of box. If you play video with `AVPlayerViewController`, try to set the volume like this and see if it works.

```
 myAvPlayer.volume = 1.0;
```

Comment: It seems only latest Apple TV supports volume control.